# Chaining Flows (collecting a Flow within the collect{} block of another Flow)

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I'm new to using `Flows`. I have a situation where I need to wait on `userLoginStatusChangedFlow` to collect before calling `readProfileFromFirestore()` (which also collects a `Flow`). The first checks that the user is logged into Firebase Auth, while the second downloads the user's profile information from Firestore. The code I have works, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the intended way.

Question: Is it standard practice to "chain" `Flows` like this? Would you do it any differently?

```
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.userLoginStatusChangedFlow.collect { userLoggedIn: Boolean? ->
                if (userLoggedIn == true) {
                    launch {
                        readProfileFromFirestore()
                    }
                } else {
                    navigateToLoginFragment()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `readProfileFromFirestore()` method that gets called above:

```
    // Download profile from Firestore and update the repository's cached profile.
    private suspend fun readProfileFromFirestore() {
        repository.readProfileFromFirestoreFlow().collect { state ->
            when (state) {
                is State.Success -> {
                    val profile: Models.Profile? = state.data
                    if (profile != null && repository.isProfileComplete(profile)) {
                        repository.updateCachedProfile(profile)
                        navigateToExploreFragment()
                    } else {
                        navigateToAuthenticationFragment()
                    }
                }
                is State.Failed -> {
                    // Error occurred while getting profile, so just inform user and go to LoginFragment.
                    displayErrorToast(state.throwable.message ?: "Failed to get profile")
                    navigateToAuthenticationFragment()
                }
                is State.Loading -> return@collect
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of unusual things about your code.

First, it's unusual that you have a Flow of a single value. A Flow is for multiple values that arrive over a period of time. A suspend function is much more sensible if there is only one item to retrieve. Both of your Flows seem to have this same odd behavior.

Second is that you're launching a coroutine from inside a coroutine when it's the last thing your coroutine needs to do. There's no reason to introduce extra complexity for this situation. Calling `launch` inside a coroutine might make sense if you need to start some side chain of actions when  you still have more you want to do in the current coroutine without waiting for those other events. That's not the case here.

Occasionally, there is a need for a Flow with a finite number of items, but it's more common for Flows to be theoretically infinite, because they are polling some ongoing state. In these situations, it would be odd to try to do anything in the coroutine after collecting, because you don't know when or if that will happen.

So, looking at your code, I would say neither of your Flows should exist in the first place and you should replace them with suspend functions.

But if for some reason you couldn't do that (like maybe it's a Flow of state changes and you just want to listen in on what's the latest state of something, react to that state and ignore future state changes), then you can use `first()` instead of `collect()` to make your coroutine simpler, like:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val userLoggedIn = repository.userLoginStatusChangedFlow.first()
        if (userLoggedIn == true) {
            readProfileFromFirestore()
        } else {
            navigateToLoginFragment()
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun readProfileFromFirestore() {
    val state = repository.readProfileFromFirestoreFlow().first()
    when (state) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Notice this code is very similar to how it would look if you replaced your Flows with suspend functions. `first()` basically converts the Flow into a suspend function.

Comment: This was exactly the sort of guidance I was looking for. Thank you so much! Would you recommend `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead for these one-shot callbacks?

Comment: Firebase already has suspend functions so there’s no need for using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` yourself. Make sure you’re using the `-Ktx` version of the library and then you can call `await()` on Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

first, as @Tenfour04 pointed out, suspend function  with `first` operator would be enough for your case,

if you insist on employing flow (which may be reasonable for cases like if you provide user-interactive retry), you may combine the two flows with operator `flatMap`-cluster  (flatMapMerge / flatMapConcat / flatMapLatest) and use a single `collect` to consume value

```kotlin
val  credentials = flow {  emit(true) }
val  profiles = flow { emit(State.Loading) }

credentials.flatMapMerge { value -> 
   if (!value) flow { emit(State.NotLogin) } else profiles
}.collect { state ->
   // mapping your state here
}
```